# Why does my op-amp circuit always give the same output?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have an op-amp design same with the picture seen below with TL072.I have an analog sensor that goes as Vin. I am giving 3.3V from an arduino to power it. And reading values from an analog pin.

The problem is that the output gives constant 1.2 V while sensor and resistors are disconnected and 2.3V while they are connected.

r2=220 ohm|
rf=2.2k ohm|
sensor gives output between 0-200 mV

[image: Image taken from http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_3.html]

*Image taken from http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_3.html

Comment: You have chosen the wrong op-amp. If you read the datasheet you will see that the TL071 can only get within a volt or so of the supply rails. Yours can't move either way. You are looking for low-voltage op-amps with rail-rail output capability.

Comment: Indeed the TL071 is not suited for such a low supply voltage, get a TLC271 or an MCP601 or MCP6001 instead. These are designed for supply voltages of 5 V and lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to measure a voltage that is close to the negative supply rail (so you need a **single-supply** op-amp), you have a low supply voltage (so only some l**ow voltage op-amps** are suitable), your voltage is rather low (so **offset voltage** matters). The output needs to swing near the negative rail (so **RRO or single supply**). If you increased the supply voltages (say +10/-5) to get the TL072 to work you'd run into the requirement to keep the input voltage to the ADC within approximately the range of 0-3.3V.

Your TL072 is thus unsuitable for a myriad (or maybe even a plethora) of reasons.

Follow @Fakemoustache's suggestion- and used something like a [MCP606](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/11177f.pdf). It's also compliant with any desire you may have to avoid very tiny packages- it's available in 8-pin DIP. Offset voltage is max +/-250uV so offset error in the output will be less than 3mV.

I also suggest you increase the values of your feedback resistors by perhaps 10:1 (22K/2.2K) or maybe 49.9K/4.99K 1% because your values will load the op-amp output a lot and cause more gain error than necessary. Your gain in any case will be ~11 so you will get 0-2.2V out for 0-200mV in.

Comment: Will TLC271 work instead of MCP606 because MCP opamp series isn't avaliable in where i live?

Comment: It's worse in about every way, but it should function, with the exception that it might have trouble making it all the way up to 2.2V especially at high temperature. Try 100K/10K feedback resistors to give it a fighting chance. Offset can be as bad as +/-10mV depending on type, so it could have 220mV offset at the output (40x worse).

Comment: Lastly, how much ampere would it drain with this setup? I have another component connected to arduino ( a zigbee module) and a powerbank that powers arduino with 5V and 2A.

Comment: Not much. Look up the supply current for the op-amp of your choice from the datasheet, and add the maximum output voltage divided by (R2+ Rf).

Comment: I changed op-amp to TLC271, tried with 220 ohm/2.2k ohm and 220 ohm / 22k ohm resistors and they both gave result near 0. Should i take higher resistors to make it work?

Comment: With a TLC271 ?

Comment: Yes, I am using TLC271 now.

Comment: You should not get near zero out with +200mV in, assuming 22K Rf and 220 ohm R2 (gain = +101) . If you swap the two resistors it will be close to 200mV out. The TLC271 is a single (not dual) op-amp with a different pinout so check that.

Comment: It gives around 1 mV - 60 mV mostly, 200 mV is the highest value it can get in normal usage. Normally without op-amp it gives 28 at analog reader ( which goes up to 4096) and now with op-amp it gives max 7.

Answer (score 1):

kindly increase the supply voltage as suggested in the datasheet

http://www.ti.com/product/TL072

(Note : it requires two supplies one +ve and another -ve)

Comment: I will try add a battery to opamp input and output but should battery's ground  connected to arduino's ground?

Comment: yes connect the battery to arduino ground and op-amp +ve,-ve supply (not input) terminals.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to mean +ve, -ve.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the accuracy you need, it might be simpler to use a transistor amplifier here. Maybe you can calibrate the result in software and avoid using a more accurate and more expensive op-amp solution.